# Когда используется iterator не в цикле foreach?

Tags: java, ооп, foreach, итераторы

Бывают ли такие случаи, когда нужно прописывать и работать напрямую с итератором а не в `foreach`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласен с Sergey Gornostaev, и в дополнении к прошлому посту: кроме модификации элементов коллекции, с помощью итератора можно "проходить" по всем элементам как прямом направлении, через методы:

```
MyIterator.hasNext(); //проверка наличия следующего элемента
MyIterator.next(); //обращение с следующему элементу
```

так и в обратном направлении (если после прохождения итератор указывает на конец коллекции)

```
MyIterator.hasPrevious(); //проверка наличия "предыдущего" элемента
MyIterator.previous(); //обращение к "предыдущему" элементу
```

В то время, как цикл типа foreach способен "проходить" только в прямом направлении.

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужно заменять или удалять элементы итерируемой коллекции.

Comment: Нет, разрабы просто написали этот класс от нечего делать )))

Answer (score 1):

Я только хотел добавить, что не только `List`'ом одним может быть реализован `Iterable` представьте себе допустим [`QuadTree`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), движение по `List` вперед да и назад вполне тривиально знай да меняй себе индекс, по дереву-же гулять "снаружи", не зная деталей вполне с таки сложно, однако, если реализован интерфейс `Iterable`, чтобы перейти к следующему узлу Вам нужно только лишь дернуть `.next()` итератора, а как итератор получит этот узел, дело разработчиков класса-итератора, а не управляющего кода. По-моему так (С) Винни-пух